# remove everything between 2 characters in python

Tags: python

i have string which include a lot of dates:

"30Abr2022(fri) 7Mar2022(sat) 4Mar2022(sun)"

what to do to let my output be like that:

"30Abr2022 7Mar2022 4Mar2022 "

without the names of the days...

Answer (score -1):

import re
s = "30Abr2022(fri) 7Mar2022(sat) 4Mar2022(sun)"

print(re.sub("[([].*?[)]]", "", s))

#output:
'30Abr2022 7Mar2022 4Mar2022'